# How to create and add files to a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, file-conversion

I'm writing a program to take large PDF's and convert each page to a .jpg, then add the .jpg's of each pdf file to their own directory (which the program needs to create).

I have completed the conversion part of the program, but I am stuck on creating a directory and adding the files to the directory.

Here's my code so far.

```
import glob, sys, fitz, os, shutil

zoom_x = 2.0
zoom_y = 2.0
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom_x, zoom_y)  # to get better resolution
all_files = glob.glob('/Users/homefolder/Downloads/*.pdf')  # image path
print(all_files)

for filename in all_files:
    doc = fitz.open(filename)
    head, tail = os.path.split(doc.name)
    save_file_name = tail.split('.')[0]
    for page in doc:  # iterate through the pages
        # print(page)
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
        # render the image
        filepath_save = '/Users/homefolder/Downloads/files' + save_file_name + str(page.number) + '.jpg'
        pix.save(filepath_save)  # save image
        
sample = glob.glob('/Users/homefolder/Downloads/*.jpg')
```

How would I write the code to create a directory for each pdf file and add those .jpg's to the directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can create directory and save to it your processed files, I also refactored your code a bit:

```
import glob, fitz, os

zoom_x = 2.0
zoom_y = 2.0
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom_x, zoom_y)
pdf_files = glob.glob('/Users/homefolder/Downloads/*.pdf')
save_to = '/Users/homefolder/Downloads/pdf_as_img/'

for path in pdf_files:
    doc = fitz.open(path)
    base_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(doc.name))
    directory_to_save = os.path.join(save_to, base_name)
    if not os.path.exists(directory_to_save):
        os.makedirs(directory_to_save)
    for page in doc:
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
        filepath_save = os.path.join(directory_to_save, str(page.number) + '.jpg')
        pix.save(filepath_save)
```

This script creates a directory for every pdf file and saves pages as jpg to it.